# Reduce the left padding of a dropdown button

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I would like to make a row, where there is a title on the left and several buttons and a dropdown on the right.

Now, I would like to make the distance between `Button 2` and the dropdown (e.g., `Cat`) smaller.

I guess we need to overwrite the left padding of the `button` inside the dropdown. I tried to put `marginLeft: "-10px"` and `paddingLeft: "-10px"` in the `style` of `FluentProvider` or `Dropdown`, but it did not work.

[image]

Could anyone help?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-ritchie-40tyj1?file=/example.tsx

```
import {
  FluentProvider,
  webLightTheme,
  makeStyles,
  shorthands
} from "@fluentui/react-components";
import {
  Dropdown,
  Option,
  OptionGroup,
  DropdownProps
} from "@fluentui/react-components/unstable";
import { CommandBarButton } from "@fluentui/react/lib/Button";
import * as React from "react";
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/react/lib/Icons";

initializeIcons(/* optional base url */);
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dropdown: {
    // removes default border around the dropdown
    ...shorthands.borderWidth(0),
    // removes the blue bottom border when the dropdown is open
    "::after": {
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    }
  }
});
export const Grouped = (props: Partial<DropdownProps>) => {
  const land = ["Cat", "Dog", "Ferret", "Hamster"];
  const styles = useStyles();
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
      <div style={{ flexBasis: "auto" }}>
        <span style={{ lineHeight: "2.7rem" }}>Title</span>
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <CommandBarButton
          styles={{ root: { height: 44 } }}
          iconProps={{ iconName: "Back" }}
          ariaLabel="Back"
          text="Button 1"
          disabled={false}
          checked={false}
        />
        <CommandBarButton
          styles={{ root: { height: 44 } }}
          iconProps={{ iconName: "Up" }}
          text="Button 2"
          disabled={false}
          checked={false}
        />

        <FluentProvider style={{ display: "flex" }} theme={webLightTheme}>
          <Dropdown
            className={styles.dropdown}
            style={{
              minWidth: "auto",
              display: "flex"
            }}
            defaultSelectedOptions={["Cat"]}
            {...props}
          >
            <OptionGroup label="Land">
              {land.map((option) => (
                <Option key={option} disabled={option === "Ferret"}>
                  {option}
                </Option>
              ))}
            </OptionGroup>
          </Dropdown>
        </FluentProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be many approaches, perhaps try specify styles for `Dropdown` button in `makeStyles` and pass it to the button. The value in below example can be further adjusted to suit the use case.

Forked demo with modification: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-rain-t5mgcc?file=/example.tsx:1623-2176)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dropdown: {
    // removes default border around the dropdown
    ...shorthands.borderWidth(0),
    // removes the blue bottom border when the dropdown is open
    "::after": {
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    }
  },
  //  styles for the dropdown button
  button: {
    paddingLeft: "0px"
  }
});
```

Pass the styles to the button of `Dropdown`:

```
<Dropdown
  className={styles.dropdown}
  style={{
    minWidth: "auto",
    display: "flex",
  }}
  defaultSelectedOptions={["Cat"]}
  //  pass styles to the button
  button={{ className: styles.button }}
  {...props}
>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant assign negative values to the padding. Try the same idea but on Button2, but with negative `margin-right: -10px` You then might need to move the whole navbar 10px to the right, since it wont stay aligned as it is now. You can fix it by doing the same on navbar content.

You might also try overriding `padding` with `padding-left: 0 !important`